# Book on computational data analytics and applications of data analytics

Tags: data-mining, references, finance, application

I'm looking for books / papers / articles for understanding:

1. Computational Techniques for Large-Scale Data Analysis. This covers:
   mining, cluster analysis, association analytics, MapReduce, Hadoop; out-of-core, online, sampling-based, and approximate learning algorithms, etc
2. Applications of Data analytics:
   Financial Analytics, Risk Analytics, Fraud Detection

Answer (score 1):

The "Mining by Massive Datasets" book by Jeff Ullman and Venkat Rajaraman (founder of Junglee, Kosmix which is now Walmart Labs) should cover some of the areas you are looking for.

for table of contents;

http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html

free pdf is available online (same link)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple:

- [Introduction to Machine Learning](http://robotics.stanford.edu/~nilsson/mlbook.html) by Nils J. Nilsson
- [Machine Learning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1846287650) by Max Brammer
- [Pattern Classification](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471056693) by Duda, Hart & Stork

Let us know if you find others that are good.